# Simulating stackoverflow like Tab effect

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the same effect for my tab which is in this site.

Here is what i tried: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5F2wu/)

I am unable to get the desired effect.

Can somebody tell me what am i missing.

```
.mytabs a {
display: block;
height: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.mytabs a:hover {
border: 1px solid #CCC;
border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}
a.youarehere {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-bottom-color: #fff;
height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: What tabs do you mean?

Comment: @KeesSonnema Go to your profile page in stack overflow. you will get a navigation menu for summary, questions, answers. i am trying to get the same navigation menu tab effect

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5F2wu/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabs-container">
    <nav class="mytabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="youarehere" href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tabs-container{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    height: 34px;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 15px;    
}

.mytabs ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.mytabs ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.mytabs a {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: #777;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 90%;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 9px 8px 0 0;
    padding: 0 11px 0 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.mytabs a:hover {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.mytabs a.youarehere {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
    color: black;
    font-size: 120%;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 0px 11px 0px 11px;
}
```

Comment: when one tab is active. and when someone hover on another i want to have top, left and right border, with total height less then the active tab height. and can you tell me what i was doing wrong

Comment: yeah. its fine. can you please explain what wrong i was doing. why it was not coming for me

Comment: btw you have to replace the bottom border also on hover

Comment: I tried doing it by myself. I failed. See my question. I clearly asked what am i missing. I didn't wanted somebody to just write the whole code. and as you have written i am just asking an explanation of what wrong i was doing. so that i can better understand that

Comment: @user3050499 I completely agree. None of the "answers" have even attempted to explain what the problem is and what their solution has changed. Comments like `will u do anything by urself` are not welcome here.